# DTS - Problem With Fully Qualified Table Names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dts

I have a SQL DTS package running on a SQL Server 2005 database that, for the most part, works properly.  However, sometimes it fails and I can't figure out why.

The package consists of an SQL task which creates a bunch of temp tables, a bunch of data transformations, then another SQL task at the end to drop the temp tables created in the first step.

The package fails every now and again because one of the temp tables referenced in a Transform Data Task can't be found, despite the table being one of the temp tables created in the first step.

The only difference I can see between the intermittently failing task and all the other Transform Data Tasks is the Table Name property for the Destination - it is fully qualified, ie. MyDatabase.dbo.TempTable, whereas all of the other tasks just have the table name specified as TempTable.  I have no idea why this one is different, or how to fix it.  I am assuming that this is the problem as it's the only thing that seems to be different between this one task and all of the others.

Also, if I manually execute the first step of the DTS to create the temp tables before executing the package in full, it always works.

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem may be here or how I can unqualify the destination table name?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add details of the error message thrown when the package fails?

Comment: I've just closed Management Studio (home time!), but the task fails on one of the Transform Data tasks saying that the table "CoreServices.dbo.TempBranchDivision" is invalid, or that it couldn't be found, I can't remember the exact wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was!  Turns out that the Workflow Properties for the failing task were incorrect and didn't specify the "Create Temp Tables" task as a prerequisite, so every now and again the task was running before the associated destination table had been created.  This wasn't happening often as the table was the second one to be created, so was generally present before the next task executed.  All of the other tasks had the correct workflow properties, but for some reason this one had been missed out.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to the problem table as a temp table, but it looks as though this is an actual table. I guess that you plan on dropping the table later in the package? After the package fails, have you verified that the table exists? Is the syntax for the table correct?

Also, your on 2005 now. Why not upgrade the package to SSIS? A log provider in SSIS can record much more than just the error message which would help you get down to what the real issue is.

Comment: If you are going to create and drop the tables inteh process, then by all means use real temp tables not a hacked up version of a temp table.

Comment: You're correct, they aren't technically temp tables.  However, I didn't create the package and don't have time to rewrite it at the moment as it's for a project that has been put on hold so my priorities lie elsewhere.  If I run the SQL task that creates the tables, it creates them all every time, but when I run the entire DTS package it sometimes says that one particular table can't be found.

Comment: Also, the create table syntax for each table is identical, barring the table name of course, however, the package only ever fails on one of the tables, the others are successfully created and populated every time.

Answer (score 1):

Since it fails intermittently, the fact that it uses a fully qualified name is unlikely to be the problem.  I would suspect the problem lies in some step above it and thus the table never gets created.  Or is this table created using a select into statement rather than a create table? If so and there are no records to select into, that could cause an intermittent problem like this.

Do different people run the package under different user accounts rather than in a job? Perhaps one doesn't have the rights to create a table in that schema.

Comment: The table is created using a Create Table statement - if I manually run the task containing the Create Table statement, it is successfully created each time, yet when I run the entire package it sometimes says that the table doesn't exist.  The only thing I can see that differs between this one table and all of the others (there are about 20 tasks in the package, each updating a different table) is the fact that this one uses a fully qualified table name and the others do not.

Comment: The job on the live server is run under a service account on a daily basis.  It usually succeeds, but every now and again it fails on this one table.  I have exactly the same problem running it on my local SQL Server, it only ever fails on the one table, all of the others are fine.

Comment: What so wierd is that if doesn't fail every time which is the behavior I would expect if the fully qualified name was the problem. Is it a fully qualified name to another server?  If so maybe the connection to the other server is periodically down.

Comment: The name just has the database and schema name ie. MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable - it does seem weird that this would be an issue as the database it runs on always has the same name, regardless of what server it's on. The connection settings are changed depending on whether it's on a dev machine or a production server, but the database name is always the same. Also, the DTS is hosted on the SQL Server where it is executed, so there isn't an issue with linked servers being unavailable or anything like that. It's really puzzling!